# JAXB xsd to object binding error

Tags: java, jaxb

I got error while binding the xml schema int Java Object by using the JAXB complier XJC ..I got the following error..

```
C:\Siva\jaxbw-plugin\lib>java -jar jaxb-xjc.jar xjc -p C:\Siva\jars\test.jaxb C:
\Siva\jars\Emp.xsd -d C:\Siva\jars\objects
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] C:\Siva\jaxbw-plugin\lib\xjc (The system cannot find the file specified)

unknown location

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Can you anybody give the solutions for this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running the XJC tool properly.

XJC should be executed either through one of the supplied batch scripts (`xjc.bat`, in your case), or from Ant.

https://jaxb.dev.java.net/nonav/2.2-ea/docs/xjc.html

It seems likely that you should be running it like this:

```
xjc -p C:\Siva\jars\test.jaxb C:\Siva\jars\Emp.xsd -d C:\Siva\jars\objects
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the file `C:\Siva\jaxbw-plugin\lib\xjc` does not exist. You should just do `xjc -p C:\Siva\jars\test.jaxb C:\Siva\jars\Emp.xsd -d C:\Siva\jars\objects`